# What to use to replace rivet on floor jack rear wheel assembly?

Tags: repair, fastener, jack, design

I have a [CRAFTSMAN 3 Ton Floor Jack](https://download.sears.com/own/00950139e.pdf) that I'm refurbishing. I've removed the rivets from the [rear wheel assemblies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJeEL.jpg) to make it easier to paint. What should I use to replace the rivets?

<kbd><kbd>**`Part`**

    `------------------------------`

    [`Axle width`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taaI5.jpg)

    [`Wheel width`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjZb0.jpg)

    [`Wheel hub inner diameter`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aUan.jpg)

    [`Frame axle hole diameter`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba7yD.jpg)

    [`Frame thickness`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oEjV.jpg)

    [`Original rivet (axle) diameter`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52gYa.jpg)</kbd>
  
  
    <kbd>**`Measurement`**

    `--------------------`

    `1.8365" (46.6471 mm)`

    `1.3440" (34.1376 mm)`

    `0.4335" (11.0109 mm)`

    `0.4180" (10.6172 mm)`

    `0.1845" ( 4.6863 mm)`

    `0.3830" ( 9.7282 mm)`</kbd></kbd>

I've gotten a recommendation to use this [10 mm x 1.5 mm x 60 mm class 10.9 flange bolt](https://www.boltdepot.com/Product-Details.aspx?product=17513) but it has a body length around 34 mm. Part of the wheel and frame will be supported by the threaded portion. Is this okay or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to find a hardened sleeve that goes through the frame and hole with a smaller diameter bolt that is just to hold it in place.

See:

[image]

The orange bit is the sleeve, then as long as there is sufficient thread on the bolt to clamp it will work. You can make the sleeve thicker and only use a 4mm or 5mm diameter bolt...

Comment: I'm not sure what a hardened sleeve is and I'm having trouble figuring out what exactly it is. Could you link to an example?

Comment: Quick google gives this, but there are many others to check out... https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Custom-High-Precision-Metal-Cnc-Metal_60689922247.html?spm=a2700.7735675.normalList.4.GX3swl&s=p